# Site Collection .CSS and Images in Master Template do not display for some users in SP 2016

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I'm trying to understand why some visitors do not see a *Site Collections images* and `.CSS` that I've applied via an updated master template.  The images, `.CSS` and master template are all checked in and published. The `.CSS` and images referenced in the master template are in a subfolder within the *Style Library*.

For some reason, they see the basic out-of-the-box SharePoint look/feel.

Comment: have you checked the permissions on Style library? by default in style library inheritence is broken from site permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the style library, please check that the files are checked in and published. Style libraries by default require that items be published and approved. You can change this by updating the versioning settings of the style library (found in the library settings).

Beyond that, the other issue could be the master page, you may need to make sure your master page is checked in and published as well (be sure that it is approved). Can be done in the site settings, master pages and page layouts.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Besides checking permissions for one of the problematic users I'd make sure you don't have one of these files stuck in "Pending Approval". This has happened to be before.

Open your site in the Content and Structure mode and set the default view to "Pending Approval" to see anything that might be there. I'm pretty sure master pages need approved by default.